Not able to get MariaDB error logs on a freshly installed Debian 12 server
I installed MariaDB using apt on Debian 12 along with Nginx. I am running Wordpress on the server.
MariaDB crashes every few days. I need to look at error logs to determine the cause of the crash.
There is no mariadb directory under /var/log
When running the following command show global variables like 'log_error'; I get the results below
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_error     |       |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

Output of grep 'log_error' /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
#log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

Does anything need to be done to enable MaridaDB logging on Debian 12? If so, what needs to done?

Is mariadb running as a systemd daemon? Add the output of grep 'log_error' /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf to the question.

@NasirRiley I have updated the question with the output. How would I know if it's running as a systemd daemon?

You would know by the way that it is started and stopped and with how the status is viewed. Is is started and stopped via systemctl start mariadb and systemctl stop mariadb? Do you restart it and view the status with systemctl restart mariadb and systemctl status mariadb?

@NasirRiley yes systemctl is used for it

To start with, unless you have created the directory /var/log/mysql and uncommented and the logs in the conf file at /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf, they will not exist.
First, create the directory and set the owner and permissions. This is assuming that the daemon/service is running as the default of mysql.
mkdir /var/log/mysql
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
chmod 2750 /var/log/mysql

These steps are in the conf file but I have included them here to be more direct.
The line in the conf file that sets the location of the error log is commented out. You will need to uncomment it so that it appears as:
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

Keep in mind that you can also set a different directory and file as the location of the logs such as /var/log/mariadb and do the above but I am keeping it simple here.
Lastly, restart the mariadb daemon with systemctl restart mariadb and you will see that the error log file exists in the location in the conf file. You will also see that the command show global variables like 'log_error'; in the MariaDB console outputs the following:
+---------------+--------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                    |
+---------------+--------------------------+
| log_error     | /var/log/mysql/error.log |
+---------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

